# Issues with Batch File Leaving a Space After Editing Text File

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to find a solution to an issue I'm having trying to add an extension to the end of every line in a text file.  I have a solution that works well, except it adds a space to the end after every line.  Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
Set "_t1=PDF List.txt"
Set "_t3=.pdf"
PUSHD %_t0%
If EXIST tmp.txt del tmp.txt
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%_t1%") do echo %%A%_t3% >>tmp.txt
del "%_t1%"
rename tmp.txt "%_t1%"
For %%A in (0 1 2) do Set _t%%A=
POPD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from your `echo` command:

```
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%_t1%") do echo %%A%_t3%>>tmp.txt
```